# sdFat and Serial conflict?

Tags: serial, sd-card

I am using the **sdFat** library to manage an SD card with an **ATmega1284p** @ 8MHz internal clock. I have come across a strange issue in my system, and I created the smallest sketch that shows the problem: What I do is, that i call `sd.begin()` in the `setup()`, and then in `Loop`, I open a file and write the word "test". After that, I **close** the **Serial** and I **turn off the SDcard's** power (TLV_EN signal). After a while I re-enable the power and **restart Serial**. The second time I try to open the file to write "test", it **fails**. If I, however, comment out the `Serial.end()` and `Serial.begin()` commands, everything works as expected.
Here is the code:

```
#include <Arduino.h> 

//Power Management Libraries
#include <avr/power.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>

//SD Card
#include "SdFat.h"
#include "sdios.h"
#include "FreeStack.h"
#define SD_FAT_TYPE 1
const uint8_t SD_CS_PIN = 3;              //SPI CS pin of SD card
#define SPI_CLOCK SD_SCK_MHZ(2)

// Try to select the best SD card configuration.
#define SD_CONFIG SdSpiConfig(SD_CS_PIN, SHARED_SPI, SPI_CLOCK)
SdFat32 sd;
File32 file;

const char fileName[]="COMPMEAS.TXT";     //8.3 supported filenames: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename
int count=1;

//PSU Enables
const uint8_t TLV_EN=1;

// Serial output stream
ArduinoOutStream cout(Serial);
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Store error strings in flash to save RAM.
#define error(s) sd.errorHalt(&Serial, F(s))
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void setup() {
  pinMode(TLV_EN, OUTPUT);    // sets the digital pin 13 as output
  digitalWrite(TLV_EN,HIGH);      //TLV high enable
  delay(100);
  Serial.begin(38400,SERIAL_8N1);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("Hello!"));
  Serial.println();

  //SD Setup
  Serial.print(F("- Initializing SD card..."));
  while (!sd.begin(SD_CONFIG)) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print(F("SD initialization failed. Retrying in 2 seconds..."));
    delay(2000);
  }
  Serial.println(F("done."));

  Serial.println(F("- Setup Complete."));
  Serial.println(F("=================================================="));
  Serial.println();
  delay(5000);
}

void loop(){
  Serial.print("Loop: ");
  Serial.println(count);
  count++;
  if (!file.open(fileName, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND )) {
    Serial.println(F("- SD open failed!"));
  }
  else{
    Serial.println(F("- SD open success!!!"));
    if(file.write("test", strlen("test"))!=strlen("test")){
      Serial.println(F("- SD write failed!"));
      error("write failed");
    }
    else{
      file.flush();
      Serial.println(F("- SD write success!!!"));
    }  
    file.close();
  }
  delay(1000);
  Serial.end();
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(TLV_EN,LOW);      //TLV high enable
  delay(1000);
  
  digitalWrite(TLV_EN,HIGH);      //TLV high enable
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(38400,SERIAL_8N1);
  while(!Serial){
  }
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("----------");
  delay(5000);
}
```

Here is the result on console:

```
Hello!                                                            
                                                                                
- Initializing SD card...done.
                                              
- Setup Complete.                                                          
==================================================                                                                                           
Loop: 1
                                                                       
- SD open success!!!                                                 
- SD write success!!!                                               
----------
                                                                    
Loop: 2
                                                                       
- SD open success!!!                                                   
- SD write failed!                                                  
error: write failed                                                    
SdError: 0X1D,0XFF
```

Comment: I tested your code *almost* verbatim using an SDCard shield that was designed to work with the UNO and so I used an UNO.  The only change to the code was to `SD_CS_PIN`.  This was using SdFat 2.0.4.  I have run it for at least 20 iterations reporting success on both open and write.  I have not investigated further yet.  Thought I'd just contribute that information for now anyway.  It *seems* unlikely that being a ATMega1284P will play into this, but perhaps.  If I happen to find one I *may* try it later.

Comment: Regarding your `SdError: 0X1D,0XFF`, this is apparently a [read timeout](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/blob/2.0.4/doc/SdErrorCodes.txt#L36).  Not sure what to do with that information though.  Maybe seeing how you've wired it would help.